# iOS Pinch Scale and Two Finger Rotate at same time

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

Here is my code:

viewDidLoad:

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinch:)];
[self.canvas addGestureRecognizer:pinch];
pinch.delegate = self;

UIRotationGestureRecognizer *twoFingersRotate = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchRotate:)];
[[self canvas] addGestureRecognizer:twoFingersRotate];

twoFingersRotate.delegate = self;
```

Code For Pinches and Rotates:

```
-(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}

-(void)pinchRotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)rotate
{
    SMImage *selectedImage = [DataCenter sharedDataCenter].selectedImage;

    switch (rotate.state) 
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {
            selectedImage.referenceTransform = selectedImage.transform;
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        {
            selectedImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(selectedImage.referenceTransform, ([rotate rotation] * 55) * M_PI/180);
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}

-(void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)pinch
{
    SMImage *selectedImage = [DataCenter sharedDataCenter].selectedImage;
    [self itemSelected];

    switch (pinch.state) 
    {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
        {
            selectedImage.referenceTransform = selectedImage.transform;
            break;
        }
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        {
            CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale(selectedImage.referenceTransform, pinch.scale, pinch.scale);
            selectedImage.transform = transform;
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

My rotation works great on its own and my scale works great on its own, but they wont work together. One always works or the other doesn't.  When I implement shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer the two gestures seem to fight against each other and produce poor results.  What am I missing? (Yes I have implemented `<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>`)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Every time `pinch:` is called, you just compute the transform based on the pinch recognizer's scale.  Every time `pinchRotate:` is called, you just compute the transform based on the rotation recognizer's rotation.  You never combine the scale and the rotation into one transform.

Here's an approach.  Give yourself one new instance variable, `_activeRecognizers`:

```
NSMutableSet *_activeRecognizers;
```

Initialize it in `viewDidLoad`:

```
_activeRecognizers = [NSMutableSet set];
```

Use one method as the action for *both* recognizers:

```
- (IBAction)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    SMImage *selectedImage = [DataCenter sharedDataCenter].selectedImage;

    switch (recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            if (_activeRecognizers.count == 0)
                selectedImage.referenceTransform = selectedImage.transform;
            [_activeRecognizers addObject:recognizer];
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            selectedImage.referenceTransform = [self applyRecognizer:recognizer toTransform:selectedImage.referenceTransform];
            [_activeRecognizers removeObject:recognizer];
            break;

        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged: {
            CGAffineTransform transform = selectedImage.referenceTransform;
            for (UIGestureRecognizer *recognizer in _activeRecognizers)
                transform = [self applyRecognizer:recognizer toTransform:transform];
            selectedImage.transform = transform;
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

You'll need this helper method:

```
- (CGAffineTransform)applyRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer toTransform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
{
    if ([recognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(rotation)])
        return CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, [(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer rotation]);
    else if ([recognizer respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
        CGFloat scale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer scale];
        return CGAffineTransformScale(transform, scale, scale);
    }
    else
        return transform;
}
```

This works if you're just allowing rotating and scaling.  (I even tested it!)

If you want to add panning, use a separate action method and just adjust `selectedImage.center`.  Trying to do panning with rotation and scaling using `selectedImage.transform` is much more complicated.

Comment: Can you give me a code example of how I could apply both at the same time? my UIRotationGestureRecognizer doesn't have a "scale" property and my UIPinchGestureRecognizer doesn't have a "rotation" property.  And im not sure which Affine I would use to do both at the same time.

Comment: Works beautifully. I am much better off having this knowledge thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.  BTW I changed the last bit about how to do panning.  Also, you can put gesture recognizers in your XIB and then you don't have to create them with code in `viewDidLoad`.  Just drag a recognizer onto a view, then hook up the recognizer's delegate and action outlets with control-drags from the recognizer to File's Owner.

Comment: where handleGesture function from?

Comment: what is SMImage? is it third party?

Comment: Is this approach still valid for Swift 5 and iOS 13+? I used it, but had to translate it to Swift and couldn't make both transformation types work at the same time. That is, if I start with a pinch (resize) and then try to rotate - rotation starts with the original scale (image goes back to scale = 1), and not the current one. I just have an image view which fills the entire safe area, similar to the detailed photo view in the Photos app.

Answer (score 13):

Swift 3 with Pan, Rotate and Pinch

```
// MARK: - Gesturies

    func transformUsingRecognizer(_ recognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, transform: CGAffineTransform) -> CGAffineTransform {

        if let rotateRecognizer = recognizer as? UIRotationGestureRecognizer {
            return transform.rotated(by: rotateRecognizer.rotation)
        }

        if let pinchRecognizer = recognizer as? UIPinchGestureRecognizer {
            let scale = pinchRecognizer.scale
            return transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)
        }

        if let panRecognizer = recognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
            let deltaX = panRecognizer.translation(in: imageView).x
            let deltaY = panRecognizer.translation(in: imageView).y
            return transform.translatedBy(x: deltaX, y: deltaY)
        }

        return transform
    }

    var initialTransform: CGAffineTransform?

    var gestures = Set<UIGestureRecognizer>(minimumCapacity: 3)

    @IBAction func processTransform(_ sender: Any) {

        let gesture = sender as! UIGestureRecognizer

        switch gesture.state {

        case .began:
            if gestures.count == 0 {
                initialTransform = imageView.transform
            }
            gestures.insert(gesture)

        case .changed:
            if var initial = initialTransform {
                gestures.forEach({ (gesture) in
                    initial = transformUsingRecognizer(gesture, transform: initial)
                })
                imageView.transform = initial
            }

        case .ended:
            gestures.remove(gesture)

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {

        return true
    }
```

Comment: Did you tested it?

Comment: @RoiMulia sure. Using it in the real app(not in prod yet). Whats wrong?

Comment: Hey Mike, sorry for stressing. Nothing's wrong. Just wanted to ask if it's already tested to make sure it's safe to use (just in case i've missed some end scenarios)

Comment: This does not work I can confirm. If the view is rotated, pan gesture does not work properly in Y direction.

Comment: Few years late but this worked perfectly for me.
Saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 8):

For this to happen you need to implement gesture delegate `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer` and put what gestures you would like to recognize simultaneously.

```
// ensure that the pinch and rotate gesture recognizers on a particular view can all recognize simultaneously
// prevent other gesture recognizers from recognizing simultaneously
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    // if the gesture recognizers's view isn't one of our views, don't allow simultaneous recognition
    if (gestureRecognizer.view != firstView && gestureRecognizer.view != secondView)
        return NO;

    // if the gesture recognizers are on different views, don't allow simultaneous recognition
    if (gestureRecognizer.view != otherGestureRecognizer.view)
        return NO;

    // if either of the gesture recognizers is the long press, don't allow simultaneous recognition
    if ([gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]] || [otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

This code needs to be modified to the view for which you want simultaneous gesture recognisers. The above code is what you need.

Comment: He's already got a `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` that always returns YES.

Answer (score 0):

This example does not use gesture recognizers, and directly computes the transformation matrix. It also properly handles one-to-two finger transitions.

```
class PincherView: UIView {

    override var bounds :CGRect {
        willSet(newBounds) {
            oldBounds = self.bounds
        } didSet {
            self.imageLayer.position = ┼self.bounds
            self._adjustScaleForBoundsChange()
        }
    }
    var oldBounds :CGRect

    var touch₁  :UITouch?
    var touch₂  :UITouch?
    var p₁      :CGPoint?  // point 1 in image coordiate system
    var p₂      :CGPoint?  // point 2 in image coordinate system
    var p₁ʹ     :CGPoint?  // point 1 in view coordinate system
    var p₂ʹ     :CGPoint?  // point 2 in view coordinate system

    var image   :UIImage? {
        didSet {self._reset()}
    }
    var imageLayer :CALayer
    var imageTransform :CGAffineTransform {
        didSet {
            self.backTransform = self.imageTransform.inverted()
            self.imageLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeAffineTransform(self.imageTransform)
        }
    }
    var backTransform  :CGAffineTransform
    var solutionMatrix :HXMatrix?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.oldBounds = CGRect.zero
        let layer = CALayer();
        self.imageLayer = layer
        self.imageTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        self.backTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.oldBounds = self.bounds
        self.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let pʹ = touch.location(in: self).applying(self._backNormalizeTransform())
            let p = pʹ.applying(self.backTransform)
            if self.touch₁ == nil {
                self.touch₁ = touch
                self.p₁ʹ = pʹ
                self.p₁ = p
            } else if self.touch₂ == nil {
                self.touch₂ = touch
                self.p₂ʹ = pʹ
                self.p₂ = p
            }
        }
        self.solutionMatrix = self._computeSolutionMatrix()
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            let pʹ = touch.location(in: self).applying(self._backNormalizeTransform())
            if self.touch₁ == touch {
                self.p₁ʹ = pʹ
            } else if self.touch₂ == touch {
                self.p₂ʹ = pʹ
            }
        }

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(true, forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions)
        // Whether you're using 1 finger or 2 fingers
        if let q₁ʹ = self.p₁ʹ, let q₂ʹ = self.p₂ʹ {
            self.imageTransform = self._computeTransform(q₁ʹ, q₂ʹ)
        } else if let q₁ʹ = (self.p₁ʹ != nil ? self.p₁ʹ : self.p₂ʹ) {
            self.imageTransform = self._computeTransform(q₁ʹ, CGPoint(x:q₁ʹ.x + 10, y:q₁ʹ.y + 10))
        }
        CATransaction.commit()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
            if self.touch₁ == touch {
                self.touch₁ = nil
                self.p₁ = nil
                self.p₁ʹ = nil
            } else if self.touch₂ == touch {
                self.touch₂ = nil
                self.p₂ = nil
                self.p₂ʹ = nil
            }
        }
        self.solutionMatrix = self._computeSolutionMatrix()
    }

    //MARK: Private Methods

    private func _reset() {
        guard
            let image = self.image,
            let cgimage = image.cgImage else {
                return
        }

        let r = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:cgimage.width, height:cgimage.height)
        imageLayer.contents = cgimage;
        imageLayer.bounds = r
        imageLayer.position = ┼self.bounds
        self.imageTransform = self._initialTransform()
    }

    private func _normalizeTransform() -> CGAffineTransform {
        let center = ┼self.bounds
        return CGAffineTransform(translationX: center.x, y: center.y)
    }

    private func _backNormalizeTransform() -> CGAffineTransform {
        return self._normalizeTransform().inverted();
    }

    private func _initialTransform() -> CGAffineTransform {
        guard let image = self.image, let cgimage = image.cgImage else {
            return CGAffineTransform.identity;
        }
        let r = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:cgimage.width, height:cgimage.height)
        let s = r.scaleIn(rect: self.bounds)
        return CGAffineTransform(scaleX: s, y: s)
    }

    private func _adjustScaleForBoundsChange() {
        guard let image = self.image, let cgimage = image.cgImage else {
            return
        }
        let r = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:cgimage.width, height:cgimage.height)
        let oldIdeal = r.scaleAndCenterIn(rect: self.oldBounds)
        let newIdeal = r.scaleAndCenterIn(rect: self.bounds)
        let s = newIdeal.height / oldIdeal.height
        self.imageTransform = self.imageTransform.scaledBy(x: s, y: s)
    }

    private func _computeSolutionMatrix() -> HXMatrix? {
        if let q₁ = self.p₁, let q₂ = self.p₂ {
            return _computeSolutionMatrix(q₁, q₂)
        } else if let q₁ = self.p₁, let q₁ʹ = self.p₁ʹ {
            let q₂ = CGPoint(x: q₁ʹ.x + 10, y: q₁ʹ.y + 10).applying(self.backTransform)
            return _computeSolutionMatrix(q₁, q₂)
        } else if let q₂ = self.p₂, let q₂ʹ = self.p₂ʹ {
            let q₁ = CGPoint(x: q₂ʹ.x + 10, y: q₂ʹ.y + 10).applying(self.backTransform)
            return _computeSolutionMatrix(q₂, q₁)
        }
        return nil
    }

    private func _computeSolutionMatrix(_ q₁:CGPoint, _ q₂:CGPoint) -> HXMatrix {
        let x₁ = Double(q₁.x)
        let y₁ = Double(q₁.y)
        let x₂ = Double(q₂.x)
        let y₂ = Double(q₂.y)
        let A = HXMatrix(rows: 4, columns: 4, values:[
            x₁, -y₁, 1, 0,
            y₁,  x₁, 0, 1,
            x₂, -y₂, 1, 0,
            y₂,  x₂, 0, 1
        ])
        return A.inverse()
    }

    private func _computeTransform(_ q₁ʹ:CGPoint, _ q₂ʹ:CGPoint) -> CGAffineTransform {
        guard let solutionMatrix = self.solutionMatrix else {
            return CGAffineTransform.identity
        }

        let B = HXMatrix(rows: 4, columns: 1, values: [
            Double(q₁ʹ.x),
            Double(q₁ʹ.y),
            Double(q₂ʹ.x),
            Double(q₂ʹ.y)
            ])
        let C = solutionMatrix ⋅ B

        let  U = CGFloat(C[0,0])
        let  V = CGFloat(C[1,0])
        let tx = CGFloat(C[2,0])
        let ty = CGFloat(C[3,0])

        var  t :CGAffineTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        t.a  =  U; t.b  = V
        t.c  = -V; t.d  = U
        t.tx = tx; t.ty = ty

        return t
    }
}
```