# Ios transform view like map

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, apple-maps

I need transform (zoom, rotate or zoom + rotate, may be move) some view like map. I'm trying use `UIScrollView` and `UIRotateGestureRecognizer` but this solution very bad. Then i think about use `MKMapView` and my custom overlay, but i don't understand how transform `UIView` to `MKOverlay` (and i also need remove map and disable very big/small zoom). I think i should make this steps:

> 1) Create new `MKMapView` and configure frame
>
> 2) Get my custom view
>
> 3) Transform my view to `MKOverlay`
>
> 4) Add `MKOverlay` to `MKMapView`
>
> 5) Remove map from `MKMapView`
>
> 6) Add some scope for map (like zoom)

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108768/ios-pinch-scale-and-two-finger-rotate-at-same-time

Comment: @JohnFarkerson no, it's not work correct