# UIPinchGestureRecognizer is not working after UIRotationGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, simultaneous

I have 2 gesture recognizers (rotation and pinch) on a UIView. They are working well stand-alone. If I rotate after pinch, still working well. But if I pinch after rotate, pinch is not working.

- pinch : working.
- rotate : working.
- (rotate -> pinch) : not working.
- (pinch -> rotate) : working.
- (pinch -> rotate -> pinch) : not working.

Here is my code:

```
//gestures

  lazy var zoomGesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer = {
    let zoom = UIPinchGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handleZoom(_:)))
    zoom.delegate = self
    activeLayer.addGestureRecognizer(zoom)
    return zoom
  }()

  lazy var rotationGesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer = {
    let rotation = UIRotationGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(handleRotation(_:)))
    rotation.delegate = self
    activeLayer.addGestureRecognizer(rotation)
    return rotation
  }()

//handlers

  @objc func handleZoom(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
      if activeLayer.initialTransform == nil {
        activeLayer.initialTransform = activeLayer.transform
      }
    } else if gesture.state == .changed {
      let scale = gesture.scale
      activeLayer.transform = activeLayer.initialTransform!.concatenating(CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
    } else {
      activeLayer.initialTransform = nil
    }
  }

  @objc func handleRotation(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began {
      if activeLayer.initialTransform == nil {
        activeLayer.initialTransform = activeLayer.transform
      }
    } else if gesture.state == .changed {
      let rotation = gesture.rotation
      activeLayer.transform = activeLayer.initialTransform!.concatenating(CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: rotation))
    } else {
      activeLayer.initialTransform = nil
    }
  }

  // delegate method

  func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
  }
```

What am I doing wrong or miss? Thank you.

Comment: Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108768/ios-pinch-scale-and-two-finger-rotate-at-same-time), seems to be a similar issue.

Comment: I’ve already cheched that without luck.

Comment: How did you utilise that activeLayer?

Comment: @iOSTeam, there is nothing considerable. It is an UIView subclass, only has a variable named `initialTransform` to hold transform info when the gesture began.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement here is working solutions.

**Swift 4**

```
     //
     //  ViewController.swift
     //  GestureRecognizerQuestions
     //
     //  Created by Test User.
     //  Copyright © . All rights reserved.
     //

     import UIKit

     class ViewController: UIViewController , UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

        var activeView : UIView!
        var initialTransform : CGAffineTransform?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            activeView = UIView(frame: self.view.frame)
            activeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            self.view.addSubview(activeView)

            let rotation = UIRotationGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: #selector(handleRotation(_:)))
            rotation.delegate = self
            activeView.addGestureRecognizer(rotation)

            let zoomGesture = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self , action: #selector(handleZoom(_:)))
            zoomGesture.delegate = self
            activeView.addGestureRecognizer(zoomGesture)


        }

        //handlers

        @objc func handleZoom(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
            if gesture.state == .began {
                if self.initialTransform == nil {
                    self.initialTransform = activeView.transform
                }
            } else if gesture.state == .changed {
                let scale = gesture.scale
                activeView.transform = self.initialTransform!.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale))
            }  else if gesture.state == .ended {
                self.initialTransform = nil
            }
        }

        @objc func handleRotation(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
            if gesture.state == .began {
                if self.initialTransform == nil {
                    self.initialTransform = activeView.transform
                }
            } else if gesture.state == .changed {
                let rotation = gesture.rotation
                activeView.transform = self.initialTransform!.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotation))
            } else if gesture.state == .ended {
                self.initialTransform = nil
            }
        }

        // delegate method
        func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
            return true
        }
     }
```

Comment: Hey @Arda Oğul Üçpınar Did you find my solution helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I learned that using `initialTransform` to hold starting transform state is a stupid thing to do. Because everytime a gesture started, it is changing the initialTransform, which causes some unexpected behaviors.

Instead, I reset gestures's `scale` and `rotation` every time after applying to the real transfrom of view.

Here is the code:

```
  // .... gesture implementations etc ....

  @objc func handleZoom(_ gesture: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let activeLayer = activeLayer else {
      return
    }
    let scale = gesture.scale

    // apply scale
    activeLayer.transform = activeLayer.transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)

    // reset scale to the default value 
    gesture.scale = 1
  }

  @objc func handleRotation(_ gesture: UIRotationGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let activeLayer = activeLayer else {
      return
    }

    let rotation = gesture.rotation

    // apply rotation
    activeLayer.transform = activeLayer.transform.rotated(by: rotation)

    // reset rotation to the default value.
    gesture.rotation = 0
  }
```